# Having two side-by-side DIVs with the same height, how do I keep their contents also aligned when content's length keeps changing?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have two side-by-side DIVs with the same height, how do I keep their contents also aligned with each other, when their content's length is changing?

Is this possible in CSS or JQuery?

I have four rows per DIV with content as follows
- Title
- Date and Time
- Address
- Blank row 
*button*

Sometimes the Title will have 3 lines so the height of the whole DIV will have to adjust, but I need to have it aligned with the other DIV.

[image]

Can you please help?

Comment: share your code

Comment: Please share your code

Comment: This is not possible without fixed heights (or javascript). There is **no** CSS method for equalising heights of elements that do not share a parent.

Comment: Hi @Paulie_D, they belong to the same row that is why their height is same. Is it possible to adjust the contents from the first div to second div, or other way around?

Comment: @Ragome As I said...no this is not possible. You can't align or equalise heights of elements that do not share a parent.

Answer (score -1):

I get your idea,

giving the 2 divs an outer div

and setting the height of the 2 divs to auto

will make your divs the same height, and also the content inside will fit nicely,

give the outerdiv height auto aswell to make it sit around the content.

Also i used flexbox to set the divs next to eachother and word-break to make sure the content will break and not just float outside the divs

```css
.outer{height:auto;width:auto; background:green;display:flex;flex-direction:row;}
.inner{width: 50%; /*just add your width here*/ height:auto;border:5px solid blue;word-break: break-all;}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
   <div class="inner"></div>
   <div class="inner"><h1>
   vgbhjgvfcgyhbjnvgbhjgvfcgyhbjnvgbhjgvfcgyhbjnvgbhjgvfcgyhbjnvgbhjgvfcgyhbjnvgbhjgvfcgyhbjnvgbhjgvfcgyhbjnvgbhjgvfcgyhbjnvgbhjgvfcgyhbjnvgbhjgvfcgyhbjnvgbhjgvfcgyhbjnvgbhjgvfcgyhbjnvgbhjgvfcgyhbjnvgbhjgvfcgyhbjnvgbhjgvfcgyhbjnvgbhjgvfcgyhbjnvgbhjgvfcgyhbjnvgbhjgvfcgyhbjnvgbhjgvfcgyhbjnvgbhjgvfcgyhbjnvgbhjgvfcgyhbjnvgbhjgvfcgyhbjnvgbhjgvfcgyhbjnvgbhjgvfcgyhbjnvgbhjgvfcgyhbjnvgbhjgvfcgyhbjnvgbhjgvfcgyhbjnvgbhjgvfcgyhbjnvgbhjgvfcgyhbjnvgbhjgvfcgyhbjnvgbhjgvfcgyhbjnvgbhjgvfcgyhbjnvgbhjgvfcgyhbjnvgbhjgvfcgyhbjnvgbhjgvfcgyhbjnvgbhjgvfcgyhbjnvgbhjgvfcgyhbjnvgbhjgvfcgyhbjnvgbhjgvfcgyhbjnvgbhjgvfcgyhbjnvgbhjgvfcgyhbjnvgbhjgvfcgyhbjnvgbhjgvfcgyhbjnvgbhjgvfcgyhbjnvgbhjgvfcgyhbjnvgbhjgvfcgyhbjnvgbhjgvfcgyhbjnvgbhjgvfcgyhbjnvgbhjgvfcgyhbjnvgbhjgvfcgyhbjnvgbhjgvfcgyhbjnvgbhjgvfcgyhbjnvgbhjgvfcgyhbjnvgbhjgvfcgyhbjnvgbhjgvfcgyhbjnvgbhjgvfcgyhbjnvgbhjgvfcgyhbjnvgbhjgvfcgyhbjnvgbhjgvfcgyhbjnvgbhjgvfcgyhbjnvgbhjgvfcgyhbjnvgbhjgvfcgyhbjnvgbhjgvfcgyhbjnvgbhjgvfcgyhbjnvgbhjgvfcgyhbjnvgbhjgvfcgyhbjnvgbhjgvfcgyhbjnvgbhjgvfcgyhbjnvgbhjgvfcgyhbjnvgbhjgvfcgyhbjnvgbhjgvfcgyhbjnvgbhjgvfcgyhbjnvgbhjgvfcgyhbjnvgbhjgvfcgyhbjnvgbhjgvfcgyhbjnvgbhjgvfcgyhbjnvgbhjgvfcgyhbjnvgbhjgvfcgyhbjnvgbhjgvfcgyhbjnvgbhjgvfcgyhbjnvgbhjgvfcgyhbjnvgbhjgvfcgyhbjnvgbhjgvfcgyhbjnvgbhjgvfcgyhbjnvgbhjgvfcgyhbjn
   </h1></div>
</div>
```

Haveing the content line the same height if only 1 is long enough to break(so the other normally won't) will be more difficult,

to get that done you'll probably have to add some jquery to check the height of your content and if its more then 50px forinstance then the other one should become the same value